# Quadratic Equations - One rational solution?

Tags: rational-numbers, quadratics

I have a question that I am working on:

Which of the following will give one rational solution?

```
4x^2 = 9
4x^2 - 12x = -9
x^2 = 5
x^2 - 2x + 14 = 0
2x^2 = x
```

I am not asking for the answer, I am actually trying to understand what the question means. i.e. What does it mean when it says "one rational solution"?

Comment: *What is a rational solution?* - [This is](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1242778).

Comment: Do you know what a rational _number_ is?

Comment: @columbus8myhw I do now, because of the answers below.

Comment: @Integrator, yes I am quite aware of how the stack exchange family of sites work. I almost accepted your answer but then realised you only addresses what a rational solution, not what it means to only have "one rational solution". (Which I now understand is having a rational solution where the discriminant evaluates to 0, meaning the parabola will not cross the x axis twice)

Comment: @Integrator, that's what happens to a guy when he hasn't done any math in a few years and has to help out a friends son with his homework :) Edit your answer and add that bit and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Thanks @Integrator, forgive my slowness of accepting your answer, I don't check in here every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example $$4x^2 = 9 \implies x=\pm\frac{3}{2}\tag{rational solutions}$$

and

$$x^2 = 5\implies x=\sqrt5\tag{irrational solutions}$$

for a general quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$

by using quadratic formula we get, $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Now notice that for roots to be rational $b^2-4ac$ must be a perfect square and to have only one rational solution to $ax^2+bx+c=0$ we must have

$$x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$\implies\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0\implies \Delta=0$$

Answer (score 1):

A rational solution will be a solution that is a rational number.

That is, the number will be of the form $$\dfrac{p}{q}, \text{ where }p,q\in\mathbb{Z}, q\neq 0$$

Comment: I am a bit of a beginner, would it be possible to elaborate on your answer in layman's terms

Comment: Sure. It is just the ratio of two whole numbers (also known as integers,denoted by $\mathbb{Z}$). Even if the denominator of the fraction is $1$, it can still be a rational number if the numerator is an integer. Some examples of rational numbers are: $\frac{1}{2}$, because both $1$ and $2$ are whole numbers, $\frac{5}{2}$, since both $5$ and $2$ are whole numbers, $\frac{-34}{3}$, since both $-34$ and $3$ are whole numbers. Any whole number is a rational number as well, because say if I give you the number $17$. You can write that as $\frac{17}{1}$, and both $17$ and $1$ are whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A quadratic equation that has only one rational solution will be one where:

- The discriminant equates to 0. (the expression underneath the square root sign will equal 0) This means that the curve will not cross the x-axis in two places.
- The solution is a rational one